# How to await async method inside ExecutePostProcessingAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I use the code from http://arcware.net/upload-and-download-files-with-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage/ to upload blobs to azure. With the method ExecutePostProcessingAsync() I would like to call a method that resizes images and that uses async code.

The method i want to use it in looks(shrinked) like this:

```
            public override Task ExecutePostProcessingAsync()
            {
              //some code


              //I would like to await the image resizer method here before going any further
              resizer.ScaleImage();

             //Some more code here before returning
             return base.ExecutePostProcessingAsync();
            }
```

If i add async to the method like this: public override async Task ExecutePostProcessingAsync()

5+ errors will pop up with reference issues and also the error:

"is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?"

**Questions:**

Is there anyway to await an method inside this method? Any help or input appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `return await base.ExecutePostProcessingAsync();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` keyword enables the use of the `await` keyword. With that said, the correct syntax is to not return the `Task` that represents the operation, but rather simply `await` it. Consider the following:

```
public override async Task ExecutePostProcessingAsync()
{
    await resizer.ScaleImageAsync();
    await base.ExecutePostProcessingAsync();
}
```

Notice how instead of trying to return the `Task` that represents the base execution, i.e.; `base.ExecutePostProcessingAsync()` we simply `await` instead.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but i get the same error messages

Comment: @mattias try the updated version. No reason to return at all, simply `await`.